# log4j limit Appender to a specific Level

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to programmatically configure Log4j. I'm trying to add several appenders to a logger in which level is set to ALL.
Also there is no other appenders (I used removeallAppenders).

But I'm  surprised when I'm calling the logger in INFO LEVEL, and in WARN LEVEL
that I have 2 outputs.
What I need is only print level that I configured in the appender.

Here is a bit of code I used:

```
    LoggerFactory loggerr = new LoggerFactory("myLoggerName","","");

    logger.removeAllAppenders();
    ConsoleAppender caWarn = new ConsoleAppender();
    caWarn.setLayout(layout);
    caWarn.setName("warnconsole");
    caWarn.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
    caWarn.activateOptions();
    logger.addAppender(caWarn);

    loggerr.info("infooo");
    loggerr.warn("warning");
```

How can I only print the info logs?

Comment: warn has higher prio than info. So if you set the level to info, it will print info and warn (and error and fatal). You might be able to [filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter) the output but I haven't done that before.

Comment: yes, i did it and it works,  the only solution i found until now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so like @Fildor said, i figured it out by using Appender filters.

The filter admits three options **LevelMin**, **LevelMax** and **AcceptOnMatch**.

and i limited every appender to the level i wanted, maybe tedious but still the only response and solution i found to do it programmatically

```
    ConsoleAppender caInfo = new ConsoleAppender();
    caInfo.setName("infoConsole");
    caInfo.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
    layout.setConversionPattern("%-5p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n");
    caInfo.setLayout(layout);
    LevelRangeFilter lrf = new LevelRangeFilter();
    lrf.setLevelMax(Level.DEBUG);
    lrf.setLevelMin(Level.DEBUG);
    caInfo.addFilter(lrf);
    caInfo.activateOptions();
    logger.addAppender(caInfo);
```